# Is it possible to override a .NET client's default timeout on a call to a webservice?

Tags: .net, web-services, timeout

I'd like the web service proxy class to wait more than 2 minutes

Comment: You answered your own question!

Comment: sure did.  feel free to expand.  thats what this site is for...  see the faq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to think about - yes, TheSoftwareJedi is correct about setting the Timeout property on the proxy - easy enough.  The default value for that is 100s.

You also have to realize that IIS will have a timeout setting as well and it will override the c# setting if its reached.  The IIS default is 120s.

So, setting the timeout property on the proxy will get you an additional 20s before you start hitting the IIS timeout.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the [timeout property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.webclientprotocol.timeout.aspx) on the proxy